# Find the sets for $f:R \rightarrow R$ given by $f(x) = \left|x\right|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Find the sets for $f:R \rightarrow R$ given by $f(x) = \left|x\right|$.  Let $S= [0,4]$ and $T = [-3,0]$.

Find the sets:

$f(S)$, $f(T)$, $f(S) \cap f(T)$, and $f(S \cap T)$.  Is $f(S) \cap f(T) = f(S \cap T)$?

Here is my work:

$f(S)=\{x \;|\; x \in \mathbb R,  0 \le x \le 4\}$

$f(T)=\{x \;|\; x \in \mathbb R,  0 \le x \le 3\}$

$f(S) \cap f(T) =\{x \;|\; x \in \mathbb R,  0 \le x \le 3\}$

$f(S \cap T) = \{0\}$

Is $f(S) \cap f(T) = f(S \cap T)$? NO

Did I go about this the correct way?

Comment: Yes looks okay.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's completely appropriate (unless otherwise instructed) to answer using the notation given in the problem; thus you can use interval notation (except for the singleton) to make your writing more concise.